# Multiple cookie varibles not being set using curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm automating my logging into a website using php/curl.

Though my cookie isn't getting all the necessary variables.
I used to *FireFox's HTTPFox* to watch the post and I am missing the `JSESSIONID` key/value.

**Screenshot of HTTPFox Cookie**

[image]

Though the other variables are set. I noticed `JSESSIONID` has a different ***PATH***. I guess I am missing some additional curl parameter? or maybe a second call to a different URL?

**myCookie.txt**

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

mydomain.com     FALSE  /   FALSE   0   RDMZ_ROUTEID    R4276449038
mydomain.com     TRUE   /   FALSE   0   amlbcookie      13
mydomain.com     TRUE   /   FALSE   0   txdmvtokenext   somereallylongkey
mydomain.com     FALSE  /   FALSE   0   SERVERID        13
```

Anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

**CURL Code**

```
// log in
$loginURL = "http://www.somedomain.com/login";
$username = "myUsername";
$password = "myPassword";
$gotoURL  = "http://www.somedomain.com/somepage";
$postfields = 'IDToken1='.$username.'&IDToken2='.$password.'&IDButton=Log In&goto='.$gotoURL ;
$cookie_jar = "myCookie.txt";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                        'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                        )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
echo $page;
echo "Error: ".curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You're not requesting a URL under /sso/, so why would you expect to send that cookie?

Comment: How do I request a second URL and add that info to the same cookie?

Comment: The  cookie FILE is the source of cookies for the request, and the JAR is where the response cookies are saved.   I'm not sure whether or not  this destroys existing content in that file.  Note that this may take some wizardry to work; it's fairly difficult to build automated logins and is typically pretty fragile when the prices changes on the remote end, but good luck to you.  Watch out for red herrings - most of the requests your web browser is making are probably irrelevant for auth, but it may take lots of sleuthing to find out what's required.